# PDF.js document is presented upside down randomly

Tags: javascript, pdf, polymer, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.js addon to show pdfs in my polymerjs app. From time to time pdf content is rendered upside down. Here is how I'm using PDF.js:

```
            downloadPdf: function(item) {
                var pdfJsInitParams = {
                    url: app.baseURL + item.report_pdf,
                    httpHeaders: app.user.token
                };

                PDFJS.getDocument(pdfJsInitParams).promise.then(function(pdf) {
                    function renderPage(pageNumber, eltId) {
                        if(pdf.numPages < pageNumber) {
                            return;
                        }

                        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
                            var scale = 1.3;
                            var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                            var canvas = document.getElementById(eltId);
                            if(canvas) {
                                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                                var renderContext = {
                                    canvasContext: context,
                                    viewport: viewport
                                };
                                page.render(renderContext);
                            }
                        }).catch(function(err) {
                            showToastWithText(err, 'error');
                        });
                    }

                    renderPage(1, 'report_1');
                    renderPage(2, 'report_2');
                });
            }
```

Any ideas what may causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

(Looks like downloadPdf is called multiple times in short period of time)

The render() operation is asynchronous and you need to wait for its completion before you start a new rendering on the same canvas, see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/prevnext.html example. If you don't want to wait, create a new canvas.